# Условие для удаления сессии php

Tags: php, сессия

Есть форма, отправляю например 2 значения в массив:
`<input type="checkbox" name="order[]">` , получается `$_POST['order'] = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 10 );`
Далее записываю `$_POST['order'] = $_SESSION['order'];`  При повторной отправки $_POST['order'], значения из массива удаляются и получается = > Array ( [0] => 1 ) = > удаляется. Сессия работает так же, но когда остается одно значение , повторная отправка POST  не удаляет ПОСЛЕДНЕЕ значение сессии. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно будет удалить последнее значение?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял суть задачи, но последнее значение массива удалить можно так:

```
$data = [5,3,4,5,7,8];
$data = array_slice($data, 0, (sizeof($data) - 1));
```